# Zebra stripping each block in a region

Tags: blocks, theming

I'm trying to apply this to each block in a region:

http://figure-w.co.uk/zebra-striping-in-php/

He is generating zebra striping per div here, which is fine, but I'm wondering how I would apply this to each block in a given region.

Would I use something like `block_list($region)`?

This code is supposed to go in template.php

```
function likemind_zebra($id = 'global', 
                     $odd_class = 'odd', $even_class='even') {
  static $cursor = array();
  if(!isset($cursor[$id])) {
    $cursor[$id] = 1;
  }
  return $cursor[$id]++ %2? $odd_class: $even_class;
}
```

I'm just trying to figure out how I would get it to apply to each block in a region, rather than the whole region.

Comment: `$block_zebra` is defined within the block templates to allow for the ability to zebra stripe them in a region.  See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7 for more info or to let me know what I am missing here...

Answer (score 1):

A `$block_zebra` variable is defined within the block templates to allow for the ability to zebra stripe them in a region.

See [hook_preprocess_block()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7) for more info.